# Get the current top position of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, position, offset

I need to get a position of an element on a page from the top of the element (div) to the current position of the top of the window. I DO NOT want the position relative to the top of the page (seems offset and position are doing this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the offset of the parent element, then get the offset of the child element, then substract one from the other - boom you got the information you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 var top= $('#element').offset().top+ $(document).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(element).offset().top`:

```
$(".element").offset().top;
```

and apply it to your page...
Good luck